# Can we use participle phrases the article A,an before verb+ing or verb+3

Tags: grammar

In some news, you see sentences that are difficult for you to understand. Are these sentences preceded by articles An, a, or are they participles phrases? Why participle word stolen proceeding articles An,a what kind of participles?

> Video shows the moment teens **in a stolen** vehicle flew off a bridge in Minneapolis during a high-speed police chase.

> Human skeletal remains found deep **in a wooded area** of Pennsylvania identified by authorities as belonging to a man who suddenly and mysteriously went missing almost 10 years ago.

> A shocking moment in Oscars history, 50 years on.

Comment: "in" is a preposition, so these are prepositional phrases. "stolen" and "wooded" are past participles that act like adjectives. And "a" is an indefinite article, which is used when you're referring to a non-specific item.

Comment: None of these would be considered confusing to native English speakers, so you probably should be asking your questions on [ell.se].

Comment: Is this sentence the same as the above?

E.g I am a living testimony of Naomi's expert

Comment: Not quite the same because the participle "living" is not in a prepositional phrase, it's the direct object of the verb.

Comment: _Teens in a stolen vehicle_ = teenagers in a vehicle they had stolen. _A wooded area_ = an area covered in woodland. _A shocking moment_ = a moment when something happened that shocked people.

Answer (score 0):

A participle is an adjectival form of a verb, adding '-ing' or -ed- depending on the tense.  So I can write '**Walking** down the road, she whistled'.  The tea set was useless, half of it **smashed** in the earthquake.  In neither of these can an article be used.

But the same participle forms can serve as other simple adjectives, with a definite or indefinite article.

> He entered the room with the ruined painting in his hand.

> As she passed the ruined building, she was struck by a falling brick.